# Eclipse: Why classes created manually aren't recognized?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, web, package

For example: I'm making an Web project. At some line of one servlet, I put the following line:

```
ContatoDao dao = new ContatoDao();
```

So Eclipe complains that `ContatoDao` can't be found. And it's right; this class is at another package. So, in order to test, I copied `contatoDao` to the same directory of the present class (also changing it's package to the same package of the present class). But I keep getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception


  (...)


root cause
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ContatoDao cannot be resolved to a type
    ContatoDao cannot be resolved to a type
```

Which **doesn't occurs** if I create the same class, at the same place, but using the **create class** of Eclipe. Why?

Comment: "I copied the class to the same directory" - this will only cause problems. Do you not know about `import`?

Comment: I don't know how to do import in this case, because the class contatoDao is in a package that is "brother" of the current one.

Comment: Exactly the same way you'd import a class from any other package.

Comment: But, for example: the root of this project is at package A, that is son of package B. The class ContatoDao has it's root at the package C, another son of package B. Should I use something like "import ../../(...)/package C/(..)" ??

Comment: Imports are not relative.

Comment: Not? So, how should I do it?

Comment: Are you now asking how to import a class?

Comment: It's more like "how to import a class that is at a brother package?". Like, imagine two different web projects at eclipse. I want to import, from the project/package A, a class from project/package B. The "regular" way of putting as the import parameter the name of the package of the other class doesn't work, because eclipse just don't find this path (it is at another package). Got that?

Answer (score 0):

From the Eclipse Project Explorer, right click on the Project and click on 'Properties'. Then click on 'Java Build Path' to inspect the 'Source' tab to see the 'Source folders on the build path'. Ensure that the folder where your source code resides is listed.

Furthermore, also inspect the 'Order and Export' tab and ensure that the folder at the root of the package hierarchy is listed and selected here.

Answer (score 0):

Imports are not, and cannot be, relative to the current package.

If you have a top-level package `toppackage`, containing a package `subpackage`, containing a class `ContatoDao`, then to import `ContatoDao` you must use:

```
import toppackage.subpackage.ContatoDao;
```

*no matter which class you are importing it from* (even a class in `toppackage` or `toppackage.othersubpackage`).

Comment: Ok, I'm at the following class:
"C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\projects\fj21-agenda\src\br\com\caelum\servlet" .
The class I want to import is at the following:
"C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\projects\fj21-jdbc\src\com\caelum\jdbc\modelo" .

I'm not succeeding at trying to import it. It always says that the import "cannot be resolved"

Comment: @user3708854 and when you are compiling you are in the `C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\projects\fj21-jdbc\src\` folder, and you are using `import com.caelum.jdbc.modelo.ContatoDao;`?

Comment: Ok, I was at the "C:\Users\Victor\Desktop\projects\fj21-agenda\src" folder. So, I went on project->properties->Build Path->projects-> and added the 'fj21-jdbc' project. So now imports are recognized. But I'm getting a 'NoClassDefFoundError' and 'ClassNotFoundException' for the classes of fj21-jdbc that I'm trying to use at 'fj21-agenda'. Ideas?

And thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: @user3708854 go to Run Configurations, the Classpath tab, and make sure fj21-agenda is in the list. (I think that's supposed to happen automatically, but if it didn't, then add it)

Comment: Well...thanks! None of the projects were listed there, and now both are. And now it seems that the error is not occuring anymore! But...appeared another. Due to the opportunity, do you have some ideia why the message "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql" would appear, since the driver is coppied at the folders of both projects and added to their build paths?

Comment: @user3708854 Not sure what's going on with your classpath, since it should automatically have both projects and everything on their build path. I suppose you could add all your libraries to the classpath as a workaround.

Comment: Yes! I manually added the MySQL Driver to the classpath, and everything is working fine now. Man, you are a genious. Thanks!